# If php session exists, then download file a file from .htaccess locked folder

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, session, download

I have been looking to find a good guide on how to securely download files from a website only if a user session exists.

**The files in the download folder should NOT be accessible if a user session doesn't exist.**

Therefore I assume the folder the files are stored in needs to be "locked" by a .htaccess file?
Alternatively stored outside the root folder? Which is the best?

If anyone could point me to a good guide/tutorial for this it would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See [this in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813380/231316) and maybe [this for `fpassthru`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26784775/231316)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a preferred method, or doesn't it make any difference? Which is better, store files outside the root folder, or a folder locked by .htaccess?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.”_

Comment: The benefit of storing outside of your app is that your server config doesn’t have to be aware of your app. I also host on Nginx where htaccess is not an option, so it helps there, too. Make sure you test that you can’t get hit by directory traversal exploits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing which worked well. In my scenario I store my files outside of the root folder.

```
$filename= $_GET['filename'];

// the file path and file you want to send inline
$path = $fileroot."/files/".$filename;

if(!file_exists($path)) {
  die("There has been an error unfortunately");
}

// the file name of the download, change this if needed
$public_name = basename($path);

// get the file's mime type to send the correct content type header
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $path);

// header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$public_name;");
//Use "attachment" instead of inline if you want direct download instead

// send the headers
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$public_name;");
header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));

readfile($path);
```