# Create filehosting site for registered members

Tags: php, ajax, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restrict file access to authorized php users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738500/restrict-file-access-to-authorized-php-users)

I have some concept for a filehosting site ... 
LIke suppose the file is 
http://abcd.com/xyz/ABCDEF.pdf

then the user who has logged in can only download, and should not be accessible to others ..and there should be a log in which the user who downloaded has his/her username in it ...

the thing is I am stuck how to prevent the user from direct downloading ...and i want to implement the major portion of already filehosting sites ..but stuck on where to Begin that concept with ...

Comment: you should first choose a framework to use and look at the documentation to see what is included, especially access management

Answer (score 2):

You can put your files in `c:\FILES`

No one can direct download them

Create `download.php`

```
//EXAMPLE
if(($_POST['username'])&&($_POST['password'])) //are correct?
{
     //echo the file with proper header
}
```

Comment: And if the user isn't on Windows?

Comment: Any place that is not accessible ... regardless of the OS

Answer (score 1):

you should remember that `ABCDEF.pdf` is just a webpage on other major filesharing sites.
that webpage accesses the databases and check for users, session, limits, real file location and other setting they may need.

start in uploading in a location other than website, `/var/www/files` or `/storage/` you can have multiple boxes to keep your files - multiple boxes are used for load balancing.

when an user accesses that webpage if he is logged in and can access that page the "streaming"  should start immediately, otherwise throw error or login options.

this is my idea in a file sharing site.